# Issue with Scala Play WS API: Expression of type WSRequestHolder doesn't conform to type WSRequest

Tags: web-services, scala, playframework, sbt

I have a very simple Scala Play application where I want to play around with the [WS library](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS).

I only want to reproduce a simple example:

```
val request: WSRequest = WS.client
   .url(s"https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/gibtsnicht")
   .withRequestTimeout(40000) // *
val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = request.get() // **
```

But this doesn't compile.

It says:

*: `Expression of type WSRequestHolder doesn't conform to type WSRequest`

**: `Cannot resolve symbol get`

I added `ws` to my dependencies in `build.sbt` and adjusted `Application.scala` like so (as described in the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS)):

```
class Application @Inject() (ws: WSClient) extends Controller {
```

However, this doesn't work either because `Inject` is not found. Importing `import javax.inject._` doesn't help. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
val request: WSRequest = WS.client
   .url(s"https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/gibtsnicht")
   .withRequestTimeout(40000)
```

Should be

```
val request: WSRequest = ws.url(s"https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/gibtsnicht")
   .withRequestTimeout(40000)
```

Comment: The return type is wrong. It should be WSRequestHolder, not WSRequest

Comment: The return type is correct. You can confirm it here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WSClient and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WSRequest

Answer (score 0):

`play.api.libs.ws.WS` is a Singleton object that returns a `WSRequestHolder` when you call the `url` method. 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS$.html

ie.

```
import play.api.libs.ws.WS

val request: WSRequestHolder = WS.url(s"https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/gibtsnicht")
   .withRequestTimeout(40000)
```

Comment: nburk is using an injected Controller, those did not exist in Play Framework 2.0.